# How to solve an equation system with parameters using a gauss jordan elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say I have these three equations and let m, a real parameter :
$$x - y + z = 1$$
$$3x + my + 2z = 3$$
$$mx - 3y + z = 2$$

While I do know how to write those equations in a matrix form and use gauss jordan elimination when there is no m parameter present, I don't know how I should do when working with m, from what I remember you need to treat specific cases but I don't remember at all how to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: @Moo I can't find them unfortunately...

Comment: is there a typo in your first equation?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yup there was, I corrected it thank you !

Comment: @Moo Thank you, I don't understand why this gauss jordan elimination doesn't end up with an identity matrix as it usually does...

Answer (score 2):

The matrix to do elimination on is
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & m & 2 & 3 \\
m & -3 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right]
$$
Let's do it, being careful when we need to normalize a pivot:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & m & 2 & 3 \\
m & -3 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & m+3 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -3+m & 1-m & 2-m
\end{array}\right]
&&\begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2-3R_1\\R_3&\gets R_3-mR_1\end{aligned}
\\ \color{red}{(m+3\ne0)}\quad&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1/(m+3) & 0 \\
0 & -3+m & 1-m & 2-m
\end{array}\right]
&&R_2\gets\tfrac{1}{m+3}R_1
\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1/(m+3) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -(m^2+m)/(m+3) & 2-m
\end{array}\right]
&&R_3\gets R_3+(3-m)R_2
\end{align}
Thus we see that, for $m=0$ or $m=-1$, the system has no solution.

For $m\notin\{-3,-1,0\}$, the system has a single solution.

It remains to see what happens for $m=-3$. We restart from the second step:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -6 & 4 & 5
\end{array}\right]
$$
where a simple row switch shows the system has a single solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I don't understand how you concluded that for m = 0 and m = -1 there is no solution ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise For $m=0$ or $m=-1$, the last column has a pivot, so no solution. If you prefer, the last equation becomes $0=1$. Just substitute.

Answer (score 1):

from the first equation we get $$x=1+y-z$$ plugging this in the second and third equation we obtain:
$$y(m+3)-z=0$$ (I)
$$y(m-3)+z(1-m)=2-m$$ (II)
with $$z=y(m+3)$$ and (II) we have
$$y\left(m-3+(m+3)(1-m)\right)=2-m$$
can you proceed?
the last equation can written as
$$ym(-1-m)=2-m$$
and now you must do case work!
if $m=0$ then we get $$0=2$$ contradiction
if $m=-1$ then we get $$0=3$$ contradiction!
thus we get $$y=\frac{m-2}{m(m+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient matrix
$$ \pmatrix{1 & -1 & 1\cr 3 & m & 2\cr m & -3 & 1\cr}$$
has determinant $-m^2-m = -m(m+1)$, so it is singular iff $m = 0$ or $-1$.  It turns out that for $m=0$ or $-1$, the vector $[1,3,2]^T$ on the right side is not in the column space, so the system has no solutions in those cases.

Comment: The advantage of Gauss-Jordan elimination is that it works for systems of *any* size. It might be overkill in this case, but the idea is to teach it for use with larger systems that cannot be treated with Cramer's rule in a decent amount of time.